# What is the difference between an 'sdist' .tar.gz distribution and an python egg?

Tags: python, egg, sdist

I am a bit confused. There seem to be two different kind of Python packages, source distributions (setup.py sdist) and egg distributions (setup.py bdist_egg).

Both seem to be just archives with the same data, the python source files. One difference is that `pip`, the most recommended package manager, is not able to install eggs.

What is the difference between the two and what is 'the' way to do distribute my packages?

(Note, I am not wanting to distribute my packages through PyPI, but I want to use a package manager that fetches my dependencies from PyPI)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`setup.py sdist` creates a **source distribution**: it contains setup.py, the source files of your module/script (.py files or .c/.cpp for binary modules), your data files, etc. The result is an archive that can then be used to recompile everything on any platform.

`setup.py bdist` (and `bdist_*`) creates a **built distribution**: it includes .pyc files, .so/.dll/.dylib for binary modules, .exe if using `py2exe` on Windows, your data files... but no setup.py. The result is an archive that is specific to a platform (for example `linux-x86_64`) and to a version of Python, and that can be installed simply by extracting it into the root of your filesystem (executables are in /usr/bin (or equivalent), data files in /usr/share, modules in /usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/...). You can even build rpm archives that can be directly installed using your package manager.

Comment: i have tried both the above options. First to create a source distribution and then to create a build distribution. when i create the Src Dist, it creates a .gz file which is okay for drc distribution. But for build distribution when i do bdist, it creates a two folders, one called lib and another an empty directory named bdist.win32. i want to do something like, create a distribution for linux system (maybe binary) which i can give to end users and the end user should be able to use the application but not read the code. how can i do this? is RPM the answer?

Comment: Why would one create a built distribution in Python? What is the use-case?

Comment: @MartinThoma C extensions precompiled for various platforms.

Comment: When I do python3 bdist bdist_wheel the files created (both wheel and the tar.gz contain my source *.py files. The major difference is that the gz file created with the sdist option contains a directory hierarchy and compiled python as well as src. The bdist option contains only the src without the hierarchy. The information content is otherwise identical.   Of course this is python3 and 2022  which is a little later than 2011.

Answer (score 26):

**2021 update: the tools to build and use eggs no longer exist in Python.**

There are many more than two different kind of Python (distribution) packages.  This command lists many subcommands:

```
$ python setup.py --help-commands
```

Notice the various different *bdist* types.

An egg *was* a new package type, introduced by setuptools but later adopted by the standard library.  It is meant to be installed monolithic onto `sys.path`.  This differs from an *sdist* package which is meant to have `setup.py install` run, copying each file into place and perhaps taking other actions as well (building extension modules, running additional arbitrary Python code included in the package).

eggs are largely obsolete at this point in time. EDIT: eggs are gone, they were used with the command "easy_install" that's been removed from Python.

The favored packaging format now is the "wheel" format, notably used by "pip install".

Whether you create an sdist or an egg (or wheel) is independent of whether you'll be able to declare what dependencies the package has (to be downloaded automatically at installation time by PyPI).  All that's necessary for this dependency feature to work is for you to declare the dependencies using the extra APIs provided by *distribute* (the successor of setuptools) or *distutils2* (the successor of distutils - otherwise known as *packaging* in the current development version of Python 3.x).

https://packaging.python.org/ is a good resource for further information about packaging.  It covers some of the specifics of declaring dependencies (eg [install_requires](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/?highlight=install_requires#install-requires) but not `extras_require` afaict).

Comment: The links seem to be not updated in a while. Is there any newer material out there?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Is bdist and sdist both are same ?

Comment: They're not quite.  sdist is a "source distribution".  bdist is a "binary distribution".   For a pure Python project, those things are pretty close.  If your project includes any extension modules, though, the sdist includes the source for those extension modules and use of the sdist will require a compiler.  The bdist includes the compiled form of those extension modules and does not require a compiler but will only run on a system that is very close to the one you created the bdist on (often requiring the same *distro* on Linux, for example).

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone, suppose I have to distribute some images along with Python files, because my `py` files use the images as input. When I use the `sdist` or the `bdist` option, both only include the python files. How do I also package the images along with the python files?

Comment: You have to specify which files to include.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696115/python-package-with-data-files