# Python package with data files

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, distutils

A Python package should contain some data files alongside with Python sources.

1. How to make setuptools or distutils to install the data files?
2. How can my Python code know which directories my data files are installed in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add data files to python projects setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191339/add-data-files-to-python-projects-setup-py)

Answer (score 1):

Following will answer your Q#1:

There is a concept of [data_file](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) and [package_data](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data).

Package_data is used to include documentation and data_files is used to include configuration file, messages and data file.

Comment: Can anyone emphasize that this is not a duplicate question?