# Questions about packaging the first PyPi project

Tags: python, packaging, pypi, pyblime

Few days ago I've created a little project called [pyblime](https://github.com/brupelo/pyblime) and right now I was trying to figure out how to create a proper setup.py that allowed me to upload the "right stuff" to PyPi  so users will be able to enjoy the project by using `pip` without doing anything "too fancy" like calling fancy custom dev scripts, right now the project tree structure looks like this:

```
│   .gitignore
│   configure.py
│   MANIFEST.in
│   README.md
│   requirements.txt
│   setup.py
│   
├───data
│   ├───commands
│   │       comment.py
│   │       fold.py
│   │       
│   ├───screenshots
│   │       test_simple.png
│   │       test_themes.gif
│   │       
│   ├───st_build_3149
│   │   ├───syntax
│   │   └───themes
│   └───testfiles
├───docs
│       build.md
│       contributing.md
│       guidelines.md
│       usage.md
│       
├───examples
│       demo_00.py
│       tutorials.py
│       tutorial_00.py
│       tutorial_01.py
│       tutorial_02.py
│       tutorial_03.py
│       tutorial_04.py
│       tutorial_05.py
│       tutorial_06.py
│       
├───pyblime
│       utils.py
│       view.py
│       __init__.py
│       
├───sublime_text
│       sublime.py
│       sublime_plugin.py
│       
└───tests
        run_all.py
        test_scopes.py
        test_view.py
        x.py
```

Rather than 1 question, I've got few simple doubts:

- What'd be the "standard" way to instruct setup.py to copy `sublime_text/sublime.py` and `sublime_text/sublime_plugin.py` files into `Lib/site-packages` root?
- How'd you tell setup.py to copy the whole folder `pyblime` adhoc in `Lib/site-packages`?
- Finally, is it correct to upload tests/examples/tests/docs/data to PyPi? This is, content that won't be necessary to use the SDK/library itself... If it's not, where would you include this type of data... I'm aware there exists the concept of sdist&dist folders and I've already read a bit about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292652/what-is-the-difference-between-an-sdist-tar-gz-distribution-and-an-python-egg) but the question still remains :)

Right now my setup.py looks something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
from setuptools import setup

root_path = Path(__file__).parent
requirements = (root_path / "requirements.txt").read_text()
requirements = [
    v for v in requirements.split("\n")
    if v.strip() and not v.strip().startswith("#")
]
readme = (root_path / "README.md").read_text()

setup(
    author="mcve",
    author_email="mcve",
    classifiers=["mcve"],
    description="mcve",
    install_requires=requirements,
    keywords=["mcve"],
    long_description=(root_path / "README.md").read_text(),
    name="mcve",
    # package_data = {}, <---- How do i use this?
    # packages = [], <---- Do I need to use this?
    url="mcve",
    version="0.0.1",
)
```

Ps. And yeah... I've already read the official docs out there about packaging... but if I had understood those docs I wouldn't be asking this on SO ;D . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's step by step.

---

For the first question. Mostly you shouldn't do that, instead, you should consider `sublime_text` as a package too. The structure should look like:

```
├───sublime_text
|       __init__.py
│       sublime.py
│       sublime_plugin.py
```

And you should use it like `from sublime_text import sublime` in your other packages. That's could be better as you won't pollute the global namespace too much. Or if this is not a common package that you want to share between many other packages, you can directly include it as a submodule in your main package.

Or if you really wanna do this, you can place those two files in the root directory and use:

```
...
packages = find_packages(),
py_modules=["sublime", "sublime_plugin"],
...
```

---

For the second question. As that is a package, you can add that path to packages: `packages=[""]`. Or for convenience, you can use `packages=find_packages()`. It will help you to find all packages under the current directory which is `""`.

---

For your third question. Mostly it is not correct, you just need to submit what user needs to the PyPi. For `docs`, you should use [readthedocs](https://readthedocs.org/) website. And for other examples and tests, just leave them on your Github. That's enough.